# Github pipeline to copy files to Azure VM

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-virtual-machine

I am setting up a simple Github pipeline to copy files from Github repo and install the same.

First I am connecting to Azure Login.I have taken the credentials from the service principal and updated the same in the Environment variables section.

```
permissions:
  id-token: write # This is required for requesting the JWT
  contents: read  # This is required for actions/checkout
name: Run Azure Login with OIDC
on: [push]

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Az CLI login'
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
```

I have used scp command to copy the file.

```
    - name: 'Copy to VM'
run: |
              scp ~/.azure/config azureuser@myserver.eastus.cloudapp.com:/home/azureuser/config
```

Since I was getting lost connection error I have opened the port 22 to run the above command. Even that is failing with 'Exit code 1' error.
For authentication I have used SSH key which I use to login via putty.

```
-name : "VM authentication"
run: |
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
echo "${{secrets.SSH_KEY}}" > ~./ssh/id_rsa
chmod 700 ~./ssh/id_rsa
```

All are giving the same error Exit code:1